# PlayFramework ScalaTest Testing webpages with selenium

Tags: scala, selenium, playframework

I'm trying to make some test with selenium in my app but I get this error

> [error] - com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.StrictErrorReporter - runtimeError: message=[An invalid or illegal selector was specified (selector: ':checked' error: Invalid selector: *:checked).] sourceName=[http://localhost:9001/assets/javascripts/../lib/jquery/jquery.js] line=[1206] lineSource=[null] lineOffset=[0]

This is my code

```
class CheckPage extends PlaySpec with OneServerPerSuite with OneBrowserPerSuite with HtmlUnitFactory {

  implicit override lazy val app: FakeApplication =
    FakeApplication(
      additionalConfiguration = Map("ehcacheplugin" -> "disabled")
    )


  implicit override lazy val port = 9001

  "The OneBrowserPerTest trait" must {
    "provide a web driver" in {
      go to (s"http://localhost:$port/login")
      pageTitle mustBe "Archacrom"
      eventually { pageTitle mustBe "scalatest" }
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Which version of Play are you using? Which version of jquery?

Comment: I'm using play 2.4.X and jquery 2.1.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem when running HtmlUnit tests with Play 2.4.x and jQuery 2.1.4. More specifically, there is a problem with HtmlUnit 2.18 and jQuery 2.1.4 or bigger. This was reported here:

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/5050

And later, fixed for Play 2.5.0 here:

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/pull/5786

And here:

https://github.com/playframework/scalatestplus-play/pull/40

The later is available at scalatestplus-play 1.5.0. The easiest fix is to manually upgrade HtmlUnit version to 2.20:

```
libraryDependencies += "net.sourceforge.htmlunit" % "htmlunit" % "2.20"
```

Or, of course, you can [migrate your application to Play 2.5.0](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Migration25) which already uses the updated version of HtmlUnit.

Comment: Thx! I will update my framwork . it´s the better solution.